# Need understanding on a sentence based on limits.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am studying calculus where there is a sentence in my book which is,

> The definition of limit asserts that the entire graph of f above the interval $$N_2(p)$$ lies within this rectangle, except possibly for the point on the graph above p itself.

I can't find any meaning from this sentence as a whole. I need assistance.
Here is the graph of the function.

[image]

Comment: It means that the shaded rectangle in the figure lies above the shaded line segment. Of course, this is colloquially worded, and in practice the rectangle containing the portion of the graph might be below the segment, partially on or entirely on the segment (the latter being if the function is zero close to the point $p),$ etc. The segment consists of the $x$-coordinates (on the $x$-axis) of the portion of the graph being considered. That said, the single point $(p,\,f(p))$ on the graph *might* lie outside the rectangle, since for limits the value of the function at the point is ignored.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro- Can you put this in the answer instead of putting it in the comment...

Comment: I put this as a comment because I wasn't sure what you were asking. Indeed, what I said wasn't what I thought you might be asking (I wasn't sure what, but not what I said), but I figured if I just responded to what you said and not what you probably meant, namely something involving epsilons and deltas, or something about output values being arbitrarily close to some particular value, not necessarily $f(p),$ for all input values sufficiently close to $p.$ If no one answers, I'll try to say something as an answer tomorrow. Right now I'm only here for a couple of minutes.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro- I have no doubt regarding epsilon-delta definition of limits, from the book where I am learning calculus[name of the book is 'calculus' and Author is Tom Apostol] It first introduced to me the concept of 'neighborhood' and then came to the epsilon-delta definition. I have no problem regarding the concepts but sometimes I just couldn't get what the author is saying like the sentence above that's where I need some help.....

Comment: I still intend to write an answer, by the way, but I've either been busy or putting it off until later in the day when I then find myself deciding to deal with it the next day $\dots$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro- Ok, I need an answer as soon as possible but no hurry......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difficulty in trying to answer your question is that I don't know whether your difficulties are with English, or with math, or with some combination of both. That said, here's an attempt to discuss the meaning of the diagram.

There’s probably more context before the sentence you quoted (I don’t have a copy of Apostol’s Calculus book to investigate this), so I’m going to guess what was probably said before this. You have a real-valued function $f(x)$ whose domain includes all points in an open interval containing $p,$ except possibly the point $p$ itself. Thus, while $f(p)$ might be undefined, we require that $f(x)$ is defined for all values of $x$ on both sides of $p$ that are sufficiently close to $p.$ For example, this requirement is satisfied if $f(x)$ exists for all values of $x$ such that $p - 0.0013 < x < p$ and $p < x < p + 0.0047.$

The assertion “the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow p$ is equal to $A$” intuitively means that the graph of $y = f(x)$ *comes together* at the point $(p,A).$ That is, the portion of the graph lying on the left side of $x=p$ and the portion of the graph lying on the right side of $x=p$ join together at the point $(p,A).$ This can be rephrased in the following way. Imagine there is a vertical wall, infinitely high and infinitely low, that is erected on each side of the point $p.$ Now imagine moving both walls towards $p$ so that the distance between the walls gets smaller and smaller, without any positive lower limit (i.e. the walls get closer than $0.01$ apart, then closer than $0.001$ apart, then closer than $0.00073$ apart, etc.). (I'm reminded of the [trash compactor scene](https://sportshub.cbsistatic.com/i/2021/03/18/5434ec90-1315-420d-85d7-efdf3e53bffa/star-wars-a-new-hope-trash-compactor-scene-1229790.jpg) in the first-made Star Wars movie.) The limit exists at $x=p$ means that the “vertical width” of the graph that lies between the walls also gets smaller and smaller, without any positive lower limit. That is, as you horizontally squeeze the graph together at $x=p,$ it must be the case that the graph is also vertically squeezed together. See [this diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Discontinuity_jump.eps.png/220px-Discontinuity_jump.eps.png) for an example (limit doesn’t exist) in which the graph would NOT get vertically squeezed together in this manner.

In this discussion it is important to remember that the value of $f(p)$ is not considered, and in fact might not even exist. For example, for our purposes it does not matter if $(p,f(p))$ is very distant from $(p,A).$

Finally, to rephrase this even more precisely: Given any positive vertical distance $\epsilon,$ it is possible to choose a horizontal distance (this is a possible choice of $\delta$ in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of “limit”) between the walls so that the portion of the graph lying between the walls, except possibly the point $(p,f(p)),$ has a “vertical width” that is less than $\epsilon.$ In particular, the graph between the walls goes no higher than $A + \epsilon$ and the graph between the walls goes no lower than $A - \epsilon.$ (Keep in mind that the graph AT $x=p,$ namely the point $(p,f(p)),$ might be higher or lower than this.)

In the book’s diagram, the shaded interval on the $x$-axis indicates the values of $x$ corresponding to points on the graph that lie between the imagined vertical walls, and the shaded interval on the $y$-axis indicates the values of $y$ corresponding to points on the graph that lie between the imagined vertical walls. [Keep in mind that $p$ on the $x$-axis is not one of the $x$-values we have to worry about. That’s why in the diagram there is a circle in the graph at the point $(p,A)$ -- the circle shows where the graph tends to join together, while also indicating that we are not claiming that this point is actually on the graph.]

In the diagram, the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow p$ is equal to $A$ means that no matter how vertically short we make the interval $N_1(A)$ on the $y$-axis (as long as $A$ lies within that open interval), we can find an interval $N_2(p)$ on the $x$-axis containing $p$ such that all the points on the graph corresponding to $x \in N_2(p)$ (except possibly $x=p)$ are such that they stay within the vertical bounds established by $N_1(A).$ In other words, all points on the graph corresponding to $x \in N_2(p)$ (except possibly $x=p)$ lie within the shaded rectangle shown in the diagram.

Comment: L.Renfro- Apologies for very late response, I understood you answer as much as possible, you gave an analogical explanation of epsilon delta definition using "infinitely long walls" but I couldn't relate this answer to my question, no offence, and also technically if a limits exists then f(x) has to exists for all the points that are infinitely close to 'p'(this is a thing that i am pointing out because i think it is right and not to criticize) and I have still got few doubts about limits (I will deal with this later) but thank you for the answer man appreciate it.

Comment: @Daniel Joseph: *if a limits exists then f(x) has to exists for all the points that are infinitely close to 'p'* --- Under the interpretation that "infinitely close" means "arbitrarily close" (the 1st is a lot more [colloquial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colloquial) than the 2nd, and even the 2nd is somewhat colloquial), then this requirement means EXACTLY the same as the mathematical wording (not colloquial) that I used: "function $f(x)$ whose domain includes all points in an open interval containing $p,$ except possibly the point $p$ itself".